# Does Azure TableQuery handle continuation tokens internally?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to find a definitive answer to the question of continuation tokens and the Azure Storage Library 2.0, as there seems to be significant differences between pre-2.0 versions (StorageClient) and the current version (Storage).

Aside from the MSDN documentation, which doesn't clarify the above question for me, its very hard to find information on continuation tokens which specifically relates to version 2.0 and above of the library, because earlier versions are named so similarly (CloudTableQuery vs TableQuery) search results get polluted with information about the earlier versions.

So, are continuation tokens handled internally on the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage client (version 2.0 of the storage library)?  Can I trust that the result sets I get back are the full result sets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There're two methods in question when it comes to executing queries against a table: [`CloudTable.ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.executequery.aspx) and [`CloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmented`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.executequerysegmented.aspx). The first one (ExecuteQuery) will handle the continuation token internally while the second one (ExecuteQuerySegmented) will return you the continuation token as a part of result set which you can use to fetch next set of data.